# Serialize xml to c# object

Tags: c#, xml, soap

I have been having a few problems with trying to serialize my XML to a C# object. I am getting multiple "System.InvalidOperationException".

Errors :

- InvalidOperationException: There was an error reflecting property 'MPFAvailability'.
- InvalidOperationException: There was an error reflecting type 'TalkTalkAPI.Models.AvailabilityDetails'.
- InvalidOperationException: There was an error reflecting property 'AvailabilityContent'.
- InvalidOperationException: There was an error reflecting type 'TalkTalkAPI.Models.AvailabilityContent'.

I have looked within the inner exception but no further details exist. I am sure this has something to do with the way my object is set up.

XML:

```
<GetAvailabilityResult xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <Status xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/InHouse.SharedLibraries.ServiceBase.BaseTypes">
           <Errors/>
           <HasErrors>false</HasErrors>
        </Status>
        <CSSDistrictCode>LV</CSSDistrictCode>
        <GoldAddressKey>A00009292705</GoldAddressKey>
        <MPFAvailability>
           <AvailabilityDetails i:type="MPFAvailabilityDetails">
              <Status xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/InHouse.SharedLibraries.ServiceBase.BaseTypes">
                 <Errors/>
                 <HasErrors>false</HasErrors>
              </Status>
              <AccessLineID>PRH4144561P4</AccessLineID>
              <AccessLineStatus>BTLive</AccessLineStatus>
              <AccessLineStatusVDSL>Working</AccessLineStatusVDSL>
              <DPType>External</DPType>
              <EstimatedSyncSpeed>
                 <AnnexADownstream>8818</AnnexADownstream>
                 <AnnexAMaxRangeDownstream>11055</AnnexAMaxRangeDownstream>
                 <AnnexAMinRangeDownstream>6464</AnnexAMinRangeDownstream>
                 <AnnexMDownstream>7318</AnnexMDownstream>
                 <AnnexMMaxRangeDownstream>14655</AnnexMMaxRangeDownstream>
                 <AnnexMMaxRangeUpstream>1015</AnnexMMaxRangeUpstream>
                 <AnnexMMinRangeDownstream>7945</AnnexMMinRangeDownstream>
                 <AnnexMMinRangeUpstream>876</AnnexMMinRangeUpstream>
                 <AnnexMUpstream>1500</AnnexMUpstream>
                 <MinThresholdAnnexADownstream>5129</MinThresholdAnnexADownstream>
                 <MinThresholdAnnexMDownStream>6423</MinThresholdAnnexMDownStream>
              </EstimatedSyncSpeed>
              <EstimatedThroughputSpeedAnnexA>
                 <ThroughputSpeedType>
                    <DownstreamThroughputBottom>5.43</DownstreamThroughputBottom>
                    <DownstreamThroughputMin>4.31</DownstreamThroughputMin>
                    <DownstreamThroughputTop>9.29</DownstreamThroughputTop>
                    <SpeedCategory>Consumer</SpeedCategory>
                    <TimeOfDay>Peak</TimeOfDay>
                    <UpstreamThroughputBottom>0.74</UpstreamThroughputBottom>
                    <UpstreamThroughputMin>0.5</UpstreamThroughputMin>
                    <UpstreamThroughputTop>0.85</UpstreamThroughputTop>
                 </ThroughputSpeedType>
                 <ThroughputSpeedType>
                    <DownstreamThroughputBottom>5.53</DownstreamThroughputBottom>
                    <DownstreamThroughputMin>4.39</DownstreamThroughputMin>
                    <DownstreamThroughputTop>9.46</DownstreamThroughputTop>
                    <SpeedCategory>Consumer</SpeedCategory>
                    <TimeOfDay>OffPeak</TimeOfDay>
                    <UpstreamThroughputBottom>0.75</UpstreamThroughputBottom>
                    <UpstreamThroughputMin>0.51</UpstreamThroughputMin>
                    <UpstreamThroughputTop>0.87</UpstreamThroughputTop>
                 </ThroughputSpeedType>
                 <ThroughputSpeedType>
                    <DownstreamThroughputBottom>5.53</DownstreamThroughputBottom>
                    <DownstreamThroughputMin>4.39</DownstreamThroughputMin>
                    <DownstreamThroughputTop>9.46</DownstreamThroughputTop>
                    <SpeedCategory>Business</SpeedCategory>
                    <TimeOfDay>Peak</TimeOfDay>
                    <UpstreamThroughputBottom>0.75</UpstreamThroughputBottom>
                    <UpstreamThroughputMin>0.51</UpstreamThroughputMin>
                    <UpstreamThroughputTop>0.87</UpstreamThroughputTop>
                 </ThroughputSpeedType>
                 <ThroughputSpeedType>
                    <DownstreamThroughputBottom>5.57</DownstreamThroughputBottom>
                    <DownstreamThroughputMin>4.42</DownstreamThroughputMin>
                    <DownstreamThroughputTop>9.53</DownstreamThroughputTop>
                    <SpeedCategory>Business</SpeedCategory>
                    <TimeOfDay>OffPeak</TimeOfDay>
                    <UpstreamThroughputBottom>0.76</UpstreamThroughputBottom>
                    <UpstreamThroughputMin>0.51</UpstreamThroughputMin>
                    <UpstreamThroughputTop>0.88</UpstreamThroughputTop>
                 </ThroughputSpeedType>
              </EstimatedThroughputSpeedAnnexA>
              <EstimatedThroughputSpeedAnnexM>
                 <ThroughputSpeedType>
                    <DownstreamThroughputBottom>6.67</DownstreamThroughputBottom>
                    <DownstreamThroughputMin>5.4</DownstreamThroughputMin>
                    <DownstreamThroughputTop>12.31</DownstreamThroughputTop>
                    <SpeedCategory>Consumer</SpeedCategory>
                    <TimeOfDay>Peak</TimeOfDay>
                    <UpstreamThroughputBottom>0.74</UpstreamThroughputBottom>
                    <UpstreamThroughputMin>0.5</UpstreamThroughputMin>
                    <UpstreamThroughputTop>0.85</UpstreamThroughputTop>
                 </ThroughputSpeedType>
                 <ThroughputSpeedType>
                    <DownstreamThroughputBottom>6.8</DownstreamThroughputBottom>
                    <DownstreamThroughputMin>5.5</DownstreamThroughputMin>
                    <DownstreamThroughputTop>12.55</DownstreamThroughputTop>
                    <SpeedCategory>Consumer</SpeedCategory>
                    <TimeOfDay>OffPeak</TimeOfDay>
                    <UpstreamThroughputBottom>0.75</UpstreamThroughputBottom>
                    <UpstreamThroughputMin>0.51</UpstreamThroughputMin>
                    <UpstreamThroughputTop>0.87</UpstreamThroughputTop>
                 </ThroughputSpeedType>
                 <ThroughputSpeedType>
                    <DownstreamThroughputBottom>6.8</DownstreamThroughputBottom>
                    <DownstreamThroughputMin>5.5</DownstreamThroughputMin>
                    <DownstreamThroughputTop>12.55</DownstreamThroughputTop>
                    <SpeedCategory>Business</SpeedCategory>
                    <TimeOfDay>Peak</TimeOfDay>
                    <UpstreamThroughputBottom>0.75</UpstreamThroughputBottom>
                    <UpstreamThroughputMin>0.51</UpstreamThroughputMin>
                    <UpstreamThroughputTop>0.87</UpstreamThroughputTop>
                 </ThroughputSpeedType>
                 <ThroughputSpeedType>
                    <DownstreamThroughputBottom>6.85</DownstreamThroughputBottom>
                    <DownstreamThroughputMin>5.54</DownstreamThroughputMin>
                    <DownstreamThroughputTop>12.63</DownstreamThroughputTop>
                    <SpeedCategory>Business</SpeedCategory>
                    <TimeOfDay>OffPeak</TimeOfDay>
                    <UpstreamThroughputBottom>0.76</UpstreamThroughputBottom>
                    <UpstreamThroughputMin>0.51</UpstreamThroughputMin>
                    <UpstreamThroughputTop>0.88</UpstreamThroughputTop>
                 </ThroughputSpeedType>
              </EstimatedThroughputSpeedAnnexM>
              <ExchangeDetails>
                 <CSSExchangeDistrictCode>ND</CSSExchangeDistrictCode>
                 <CircuitLineLength>
                    <Length>1903</Length>
                    <MeasureType>CircuitEstimated</MeasureType>
                 </CircuitLineLength>
                 <ExchangeCapacity>G</ExchangeCapacity>
                 <ExchangeCode>NDACO</ExchangeCode>
                 <ExchangeName>Archers Court</ExchangeName>
                 <ExchangeState>Live</ExchangeState>
                 <ForecastDate>2010-05-12T00:00:00</ForecastDate>
                 <ProductMessages i:nil="true"/>
              </ExchangeDetails>
              <GoldAddressKey>A00009292705</GoldAddressKey>
              <LineTypeDetails>
                 <WorkingLineDetails>
                    <InstallationType>Standard</InstallationType>
                    <ProductType>MPF</ProductType>
                 </WorkingLineDetails>
              </LineTypeDetails>
              <TechnologyMessages>
                 <TechnologyMessage>
                    <Code>LLUMPF</Code>
                    <Message>MPF LLU Installation</Message>
                 </TechnologyMessage>
                 <TechnologyMessage>
                    <Code>GEA</Code>
                    <Message>Generic Ethernet Access</Message>
                 </TechnologyMessage>
              </TechnologyMessages>
           </AvailabilityDetails>
        </MPFAvailability>
        <Postcode/>
        <SMPFAvailability>
           <AvailabilityDetails i:type="SMPFAvailabilityDetails">
              <Status xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/InHouse.SharedLibraries.ServiceBase.BaseTypes">
                 <Errors/>
                 <HasErrors>false</HasErrors>
              </Status>
              <AccessLineID>PRH4144561P4</AccessLineID>
              <AccessLineStatus>BTLive</AccessLineStatus>
              <AccessLineStatusVDSL>Working</AccessLineStatusVDSL>
              <EstimatedSyncSpeed>
                 <AnnexADownstream>8818</AnnexADownstream>
                 <AnnexAMaxRangeDownstream>11055</AnnexAMaxRangeDownstream>
                 <AnnexAMinRangeDownstream>6464</AnnexAMinRangeDownstream>
                 <AnnexMDownstream>7318</AnnexMDownstream>
                 <AnnexMMaxRangeDownstream>14655</AnnexMMaxRangeDownstream>
                 <AnnexMMaxRangeUpstream>1015</AnnexMMaxRangeUpstream>
                 <AnnexMMinRangeDownstream>7945</AnnexMMinRangeDownstream>
                 <AnnexMMinRangeUpstream>876</AnnexMMinRangeUpstream>
                 <AnnexMUpstream>1500</AnnexMUpstream>
                 <MinThresholdAnnexADownstream>5129</MinThresholdAnnexADownstream>
                 <MinThresholdAnnexMDownStream>6423</MinThresholdAnnexMDownStream>
              </EstimatedSyncSpeed>
              <EstimatedThroughputSpeedAnnexA>
                 <ThroughputSpeedType>
                    <DownstreamThroughputBottom>5.43</DownstreamThroughputBottom>
                    <DownstreamThroughputMin>4.31</DownstreamThroughputMin>
                    <DownstreamThroughputTop>9.29</DownstreamThroughputTop>
                    <SpeedCategory>Consumer</SpeedCategory>
                    <TimeOfDay>Peak</TimeOfDay>
                    <UpstreamThroughputBottom>0.74</UpstreamThroughputBottom>
                    <UpstreamThroughputMin>0.5</UpstreamThroughputMin>
                    <UpstreamThroughputTop>0.85</UpstreamThroughputTop>
                 </ThroughputSpeedType>
                 <ThroughputSpeedType>
                    <DownstreamThroughputBottom>5.53</DownstreamThroughputBottom>
                    <DownstreamThroughputMin>4.39</DownstreamThroughputMin>
                    <DownstreamThroughputTop>9.46</DownstreamThroughputTop>
                    <SpeedCategory>Consumer</SpeedCategory>
                    <TimeOfDay>OffPeak</TimeOfDay>
                    <UpstreamThroughputBottom>0.75</UpstreamThroughputBottom>
                    <UpstreamThroughputMin>0.51</UpstreamThroughputMin>
                    <UpstreamThroughputTop>0.87</UpstreamThroughputTop>
                 </ThroughputSpeedType>
                 <ThroughputSpeedType>
                    <DownstreamThroughputBottom>5.53</DownstreamThroughputBottom>
                    <DownstreamThroughputMin>4.39</DownstreamThroughputMin>
                    <DownstreamThroughputTop>9.46</DownstreamThroughputTop>
                    <SpeedCategory>Business</SpeedCategory>
                    <TimeOfDay>Peak</TimeOfDay>
                    <UpstreamThroughputBottom>0.75</UpstreamThroughputBottom>
                    <UpstreamThroughputMin>0.51</UpstreamThroughputMin>
                    <UpstreamThroughputTop>0.87</UpstreamThroughputTop>
                 </ThroughputSpeedType>
                 <ThroughputSpeedType>
                    <DownstreamThroughputBottom>5.57</DownstreamThroughputBottom>
                    <DownstreamThroughputMin>4.42</DownstreamThroughputMin>
                    <DownstreamThroughputTop>9.53</DownstreamThroughputTop>
                    <SpeedCategory>Business</SpeedCategory>
                    <TimeOfDay>OffPeak</TimeOfDay>
                    <UpstreamThroughputBottom>0.76</UpstreamThroughputBottom>
                    <UpstreamThroughputMin>0.51</UpstreamThroughputMin>
                    <UpstreamThroughputTop>0.88</UpstreamThroughputTop>
                 </ThroughputSpeedType>
              </EstimatedThroughputSpeedAnnexA>
              <EstimatedThroughputSpeedAnnexM>
                 <ThroughputSpeedType>
                    <DownstreamThroughputBottom>6.67</DownstreamThroughputBottom>
                    <DownstreamThroughputMin>5.4</DownstreamThroughputMin>
                    <DownstreamThroughputTop>12.31</DownstreamThroughputTop>
                    <SpeedCategory>Consumer</SpeedCategory>
                    <TimeOfDay>Peak</TimeOfDay>
                    <UpstreamThroughputBottom>0.74</UpstreamThroughputBottom>
                    <UpstreamThroughputMin>0.5</UpstreamThroughputMin>
                    <UpstreamThroughputTop>0.85</UpstreamThroughputTop>
                 </ThroughputSpeedType>
                 <ThroughputSpeedType>
                    <DownstreamThroughputBottom>6.8</DownstreamThroughputBottom>
                    <DownstreamThroughputMin>5.5</DownstreamThroughputMin>
                    <DownstreamThroughputTop>12.55</DownstreamThroughputTop>
                    <SpeedCategory>Consumer</SpeedCategory>
                    <TimeOfDay>OffPeak</TimeOfDay>
                    <UpstreamThroughputBottom>0.75</UpstreamThroughputBottom>
                    <UpstreamThroughputMin>0.51</UpstreamThroughputMin>
                    <UpstreamThroughputTop>0.87</UpstreamThroughputTop>
                 </ThroughputSpeedType>
                 <ThroughputSpeedType>
                    <DownstreamThroughputBottom>6.8</DownstreamThroughputBottom>
                    <DownstreamThroughputMin>5.5</DownstreamThroughputMin>
                    <DownstreamThroughputTop>12.55</DownstreamThroughputTop>
                    <SpeedCategory>Business</SpeedCategory>
                    <TimeOfDay>Peak</TimeOfDay>
                    <UpstreamThroughputBottom>0.75</UpstreamThroughputBottom>
                    <UpstreamThroughputMin>0.51</UpstreamThroughputMin>
                    <UpstreamThroughputTop>0.87</UpstreamThroughputTop>
                 </ThroughputSpeedType>
                 <ThroughputSpeedType>
                    <DownstreamThroughputBottom>6.85</DownstreamThroughputBottom>
                    <DownstreamThroughputMin>5.54</DownstreamThroughputMin>
                    <DownstreamThroughputTop>12.63</DownstreamThroughputTop>
                    <SpeedCategory>Business</SpeedCategory>
                    <TimeOfDay>OffPeak</TimeOfDay>
                    <UpstreamThroughputBottom>0.76</UpstreamThroughputBottom>
                    <UpstreamThroughputMin>0.51</UpstreamThroughputMin>
                    <UpstreamThroughputTop>0.88</UpstreamThroughputTop>
                 </ThroughputSpeedType>
              </EstimatedThroughputSpeedAnnexM>
              <ExchangeDetails>
                 <CSSExchangeDistrictCode>ND</CSSExchangeDistrictCode>
                 <CircuitLineLength>
                    <Length>1903</Length>
                    <MeasureType>CircuitEstimated</MeasureType>
                 </CircuitLineLength>
                 <ExchangeCapacity>G</ExchangeCapacity>
                 <ExchangeCode>NDACO</ExchangeCode>
                 <ExchangeName>Archers Court</ExchangeName>
                 <ExchangeState>Live</ExchangeState>
                 <ForecastDate>0001-01-01T00:00:00</ForecastDate>
                 <ProductMessages i:nil="true"/>
              </ExchangeDetails>
              <GoldAddressKey>A00009292705</GoldAddressKey>
              <LineTypeDetails>
                 <WorkingLineDetails>
                    <InstallationType>Standard</InstallationType>
                    <ProductType>MPF</ProductType>
                 </WorkingLineDetails>
              </LineTypeDetails>
              <TechnologyMessages>
                 <TechnologyMessage>
                    <Code>LLUMPF</Code>
                    <Message>MPF LLU Installation</Message>
                 </TechnologyMessage>
                 <TechnologyMessage>
                    <Code>GEA</Code>
                    <Message>Generic Ethernet Access</Message>
                 </TechnologyMessage>
              </TechnologyMessages>
           </AvailabilityDetails>
        </SMPFAvailability>
     </GetAvailabilityResult>
```

Model:

```
[Serializable, XmlRoot("GetAvailabilityResult")]
public class Availability
{
    [XmlElement("MPFAvailability")]
    public AvailabilityDetails MPFAvailability { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("SMPFAvailability")]
    public AvailabilityDetails SMPFAvailability { get; set; }
}

public class AvailabilityDetails
{
    [XmlElement("AvailabilityDetails")]
    public AvailabilityContent AvailabilityContent { get; set; }
}

public class AvailabilityContent
{
    [XmlElement("AccessLineID")]
    public string AccessLineID { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("AccessLineStatus")]
    public string AccessLineStatus { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("AccessLineStatusVDSL")]
    public string AccessLineStatusVDSL { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("DPType")]
    public string DPType { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("EstimatedSyncSpeed")]
    public EstimatedSyncSpeed EstimatedSyncSpeed { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("EstimatedThroughputSpeedAnnexA")]
    public List<EstimatedThroughputSpeedAnnexA> EstimatedThroughputSpeedAnnexA { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("EstimatedThroughputSpeedAnnexA")]
    public List<EstimatedThroughputSpeedAnnexM> EstimatedThroughputSpeedAnnexM { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("ExchangeDetails")]
    public ExchangeDetails ExchangeDetails { get; set; }

}

public class EstimatedSyncSpeed
{
    [XmlElement("AnnexADownstream")]
    public int AnnexADownstream { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("AnnexAMaxRangeDownstream")]
    public int AnnexAMaxRangeDownstream { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("AnnexAMinRangeDownstream")]
    public int AnnexAMinRangeDownstream { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("AnnexMDownstream")]
    public int AnnexMDownstream { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("AnnexMMaxRangeDownstream")]
    public int AnnexMMaxRangeDownstream { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("AnnexMMinRangeDownstream")]
    public int AnnexMMinRangeDownstream { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("AnnexMMinRangeUpstream")]
    public int AnnexMMinRangeUpstream { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("AnnexMUpstream")]
    public int AnnexMUpstream { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("MinThresholdAnnexADownstream")]
    public int MinThresholdAnnexADownstream { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("MinThresholdAnnexMDownStream")]
    public int MinThresholdAnnexMDownStream { get; set; }
}

public class EstimatedThroughputSpeedAnnexA
{
    [XmlElement("ThroughputSpeedType")]
    public ThroughputSpeedType ThroughputSpeedType { get; set; }
}

public class EstimatedThroughputSpeedAnnexM
{
    [XmlElement("ThroughputSpeedType")]
    public ThroughputSpeedType ThroughputSpeedType { get; set; }
}

public class ThroughputSpeedType
{
    [XmlElement("DownstreamThroughputBottom")]
    public double DownstreamThroughputBottom { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("DownstreamThroughputMin")]
    public double DownstreamThroughputMin { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("DownstreamThroughputTop")]
    public double DownstreamThroughputTop { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("SpeedCategory")]
    public string SpeedCategory { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("TimeOfDay")]
    public string TimeOfDay { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("UpstreamThroughputBottom")]
    public double UpstreamThroughputBottom { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("UpstreamThroughputMin")]
    public double UpstreamThroughputMin { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("UpstreamThroughputTop")]
    public double UpstreamThroughputTop { get; set; }
}

public class ExchangeDetails
{
    [XmlElement("CSSExchangeDistrictCode")]
    public string CSSExchangeDistrictCode { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("CircuitLineLength")]
    public CircuitLineLength CircuitLineLength { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("ExchangeCapacity")]
    public string ExchangeCapacity { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("ExchangeCode")]
    public string ExchangeCode { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("ExchangeName")]
    public string ExchangeName { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("ExchangeState")]
    public string ExchangeState { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("ForecastDate")]
    public DateTime ForecastDate { get; set; }
}

public class CircuitLineLength
{
    [XmlElement("Length")]
    public int Length { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("MeasureType")]
    public string MeasureType { get; set; }
}
```

Serializer code:

```
string Outerxml = xmlToFormat.FirstChild.FirstChild.FirstChild.FirstChild.OuterXml;
        string formatedXml = XmlFormatter.RemoveXmlns(Outerxml);

        Availability result;

        // Deserialises xlm into an object 

        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Availability));
        using (TextReader reader = new StringReader(formatedXml))
        {
            result = (Availability)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
        }

        return result;
```

Comment: Easiest would probably be to construct an object, then serialize it to XML and look at the diff to the example xml.

Comment: Maybe you need the [Serializable] attribute on all the classes

Answer (score 0):

You have this XML name appearing twice:

```
[XmlElement("EstimatedThroughputSpeedAnnexA")]
```

I found it with this inner exception:

```
InvalidOperationException: The XML element 'EstimatedThroughputSpeedAnnexA' from namespace '' is already present in the current scope. Use XML attributes to specify another XML name or namespace for the element.
```

(a good reason not to use XmlElement attributes if you don't need to!)